# 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'DoseGrid'

Tags: python, pydicom

I have been trying to use the dicompyler-core to put together two dose grids from two different dose dicoms.

```
import pydicom
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
from dicompylercore import dicomparser, dvh, dvhcalc
from dicompylercore import dose
```

I keep receiving this error while trying to import dose

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-6605335fa321> in <module>
      5 import glob
      6 from dicompylercore import dicomparser, dvh, dvhcalc
----> 7 from dicompylercore import dose

ImportError: cannot import name 'dose' from 'dicompylercore'
```

Because of this import error, I think that is why there is no attribute to be found when I try and add the two dose grids together

```
dose1 = dicomparser.DicomParser("RD.CW.dcm")
dose2 = dicomparser.DicomParser("RD.CCW.dcm")

grid_1 = dose.DoseGrid()
grid_2 = dose.DoseGrid()
grid_sum = grid_1 + grid_2
grid_sum.save_dcm("grid_sum.dcm")
```

It gives me this error

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    550         if tag is None:  # `name` isn't a DICOM element keyword
    551             # Try the base class attribute getter (fix for issue 332)
--> 552             return super(Dataset, self).__getattribute__(name)
    553         tag = Tag(tag)
    554         if tag not in self._dict:  # DICOM DataElement not in the Dataset

AttributeError: 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'DoseGrid'
```

I am new to working with dicom files and with dicompylercore. I am unsure if this is related to the dicom files I am working itself or if there is some issue with the dicomplyercore package itself. Are there any suggestions on what I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The `dose` module has been added to `dicompylercore` after the last PyPi release, so you have to install the version from GitHub, if you want to use it:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/dicompyler/dicompyler-core
```

I'm not sure how stable this version is, but you can ask about the next release on the [development site](https://github.com/dicompyler/dicompyler-core).